# Code to print corresponding CSV/list values for car program is not printing anything at all

Tags: python

I have tried to get help on this question all day, but none of the already-asked questions have solved my problem, and any answers I have asked to help me solve this problem have resulted in answers that didn't answer the question.

As it stands now, my program takes the values of MPG ratings represented in a CSV and puts them in a list. These lists represent maximum and minimum MPGs. Once the max/min MPG rating is found is where I get into my problem. I need to be able to print all the cars that have the minimum/maximum MPG value. Ideally, the models should be printed indented under the print statements for the maximum/minimum mileage ratings.

The way the CSV file is done the MPG ratings are in column 9 (index[8]). The make and models are in columns 2 and 3, respectively (index[1] and index[2], respectively). As you'll see in the code, I tried looping through the list and using an if statement to pull the make/model, but when I do that it does not work. I don't know if the files play a part or not, but any help would be appreciated.

```
# prints welcome screen, asks user what year they want vehicle data for, and asks user for file name to save vehicle data to
print("Welcome to EPA Mileage Calculator")
yearChoice = int(input("What year would you like to view data for? (2008 or 2009): "))
while yearChoice != 2008 and yearChoice != 2009:
    print("Invalid input, please try again")
    yearChoice = int(input("What year would you like to view data for? (2008 or 2009): "))
saveResults = input("Enter the filename to save results to: ")

def carData():
    if yearChoice == 2008:
        fileName = "epaVehicleData2008.csv"
    elif yearChoice == 2009:
        fileName = "epaVehicleData2009.csv"
    fileIn = open(fileName, "r")
    fileIn.readline()
    minMPG = []
    maxMPG = []
    for line in fileIn:
        line = line.strip()
        dataList = line.split(",")
        if dataList[0] not in ['VANS - PASSENGER TYPE', 'VANS - CARGO TYPE', 'TRUCK', 'MINIVAN - 4WD', 'MINIVAN - 2WD']:
            minMPG.append(int(dataList[8]))
            maxMPG.append(int(dataList[8]))
    maximumMPG = max(maxMPG)
    minimumMPG = min(minMPG)
    fileOut = open(saveResults, "w")
    print("EPA City MPG Calculator", "(" + str(yearChoice) + ")", file=fileOut)
    print("---------------------------------", file=fileOut)
    print("Maximum Mileage (city):", maximumMPG, file=fileOut)
    for line in fileIn:
        line = line.strip()
        dataList = line.split(",")
        if dataList[8] == maximumMPG:
            print("\t", dataList[1], dataList[2], file=fileOut)
    print("Minimum Mileage (city):", minimumMPG, file=fileOut)
    for line in fileIn:
        line = line.strip()
        dataList = line.split(",")
        if dataList[8] == minimumMPG:
            print("\t", dataList[1], dataList[2], file=fileOut)
    fileIn.close()
    fileOut.close()

def complete():
    print()
    print("Operation Success! Mileage data has been saved to", saveResults)
    print("Thanks, and have a great day!")

def main():
    carData()
    complete()

main()
```

Comment: Please provide a representative sample of your data.  You'll have a much easier time getting an answer, like maybe from me, if you do that.  I'd want to run this code in my debugger, but I don't want to have to create test data to do that.  Provide me with appropriate test data, and I'll do that.  Or...

Comment: Have you run this in a debugger and watched what it does?  That is how it is usually done.  Rather than staring at the code looking for problems statically, you should run the code, watch what it does, and see when it doesn't do something you expect it to.  When that happens, or by running the code over and over, you can look at the values of your variables and should be able to figure out what's going wrong.  This is programming.  We all write code that initially doesn't do what we want, and then we use a debugger to find flaws in our logic and fix them.

Comment: To put it another way, a [mcve] is required here, not just *"does not work"*. See [ask].

Comment: Ha!  I@jonrsharpe, I was just coming back to post this exact same suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You open the input file only once via:

```
fileIn = open(fileName, "r")
```

But then you attempt to iterate over the lines in the file three times using that same file handle.  You have three of these:

```
for line in fileIn:
```

Since you never close and reopen the file, and you don't do anything to seek back to the beginning of the file, the second and third such iterations will never do anything, because you've already reached the end of the file.  Using this construct does not cause the file pointer to be rewound and the contents of the file to be iterated over another time.

Since your interesting print statements are in the second and third iterations over the file, which won't produce any new lines (the code in those iteration blocks will never be called), of course your print statements are never called and no output is generated.

To fix your problem, if this is the only thing wrong with your code, just put this line before each of the second and third iterations over the file:

```
f.seek(0)
```

to seek back to the beginning of the file and iterate over the contents a second and third time.

To be more efficient, you could read each line once and store it in a list.  Then you could iterate over the list each time, and not have to read from the file three times. You could even do the strip and the split just once, making the code even more efficient.

Another small logic error that I see is that you skip one line in your first iteration over the file.  I assume that this is to skip a header row at the start of the file.  But you don't do this for the second and third iterations, so it seems that if you only add the seek() as I suggested, you'll be trying to process the header line as a data line.  This would also be solved by reading the file once into a list.  You'd skip the first line of the file while you do this.  If you want to leave the code alone other than adding the seek(), you should also skip the first line before the second and third iterations.